# Is it possible to create a admin user in one login using API's?

Tags: api, credentials, onelogin

My organisation is using OneLogin for SAML. I have to test whether the integration part works fine. I need to have a admin user so that i configure a client_id and client_secret pair through which i can hit the api end points. So i am trying to create the admin user and the client_id and client_secret pair using oneLogin api's since they use capcha it is not possible to write selenium code for the same. Is it possible to achieve this scenario using api calls only?

Answer (score 0):

The users endpoint will let you create the user, and the new Permissions API should let you assign privs to that user. I haven't used it since it was Early Access, so don't know whether it's made GA and is available for use. So, a qualified "yes" you can.

Comment: Hi @niall_atlasidentity, Thank you for the response, but for hitting the users endpoint i need a bearer:<access_token> which can be generated after creating a developer account. I didnt came across any API for creating a developer account. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You need to create an API credential pair in your OL tenant. There's no API for that, but you only need to do it once. https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/working-with-api-credentials